# Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, exception

### The question is to accept DOB from user in dd-mm-yyyy. Calculate age. If age>18 return true else false.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  
import java.text.Format;  
import java.util.Date;    
import java.time.LocalDate;  
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
import java.time.Period;  


public class Main {

    public static boolean calculateAge(LocalDate date) {

        LocalDate DateToday = LocalDate.now();
        
        Period period = Period.between(date, DateToday);

        int age = period.getYears();

        if (age>18){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }

    }  

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Date of Birth in the format dd-mm-yyyy");

        String dateEntered = sc.next();

        if(Pattern.matches("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\-(0[1-9]|[1][12])\\-([12][0-9][0-9][0-9])", dateEntered)){
            DateTimeFormatter dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
            LocalDate localDate= LocalDate.parse(dateEntered, dtf);
            calculateAge(localDate);
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong Date format");
        }
    }


}
```

After running the code I am getting the following error

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03-09-1999' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:414)
at Main.main(Main.java:26)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The pattern says yyyy-mm-dd, and then you are surprised that a date mm-dd-yyyy cant be parsed accordingly?

Comment: `"Enter Date of Birth in the format dd-mm-yyyy"` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd")` conflict with each other. Telling the user to enter a date in one format then trying to parse it in a completely different format.

Comment: You are requesting input in the form dd-mm-yyyy but define the pattern as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Also note: there is no point in doing double validation. Instead of doing your OWN pattern match, just use try/catch and when a parse exception occurs, tell the user: "wrong input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you have provided for the DateTimeFormatter Object is wrong. It should "dd-MM-yyyy"

Please replace your main block as below and it should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date of Birth in the format dd-mm-yyyy");
    String dateEntered = sc.next();
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate localDate= LocalDate.parse(dateEntered, dtf);
        System.out.println(calculateAge(localDate));
    }catch (DateTimeParseException ex){
        System.out.println("Error in entered format, please enter in dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

}
```